# Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '

Tags: java, android, attributes, syntax-error, android-manifest

I am getting an error in manifest continiously.

Tried a lot but unable to fix it.

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bot.pokego"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.bot.pokego.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Optional permission for Analytics to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.bot.pokego.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.bot.pokego.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.bot.pokego.Utils.CommonForApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bot.pokego.main.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bot.pokego.main.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAO9xX_OX2vwdUwPWVuPk2dHgzNpH3YKw8" />
        <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" />

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaIntentReceiver" />

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService" />
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.ReconnectionService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.bot.pokego" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
 Internal (not exported) receiver used by the app to start its own exported services
             without risk of being spoofed.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <!--
 FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.bot.pokego.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashReceiverService"
            android:process=":background_crash" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashSenderService"
            android:process=":background_crash" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <!--
 FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerPreviewActivity"
            android:noHistory="true" >
 <!-- optional, removes the previewActivity from the activity stack. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="tagmanager.c.com.bot.pokego" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My efforts:
I tried to remove error by myself but failed again and again !

Searched on google ....searched all possible links for it.
Any help wil be appreciated ! Thanks in advance :)
..

Problem is with debug/AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: which character is invalid ?

Comment: @Andytheandroid No idea logcat shows me error in this character only . ''

Comment: you probably have special characters or spaces somewhere where they should not be

Comment: open the manifest file with binary editor and check that there's no  suspicious character

Comment: problem is in debug/androidmanifest.xml ....main manifest is fine !!

Comment: have you made any changes lately? like installing an external library?

Comment: No error occuredwhile indexing  the project

Comment: @developer have you resolved this error....i am facing it right now

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that it has to do with the com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES permission. The newer documentation does not show that it's a requirement for location stuff: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location 
I was able to solve this issue by taking out all of the permissions and adding them one by one, rebuilding the project each time I added a permission back. The permission that gave me an issue, caused the error. Good luck :)